# Proxying each method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, coding-style

Is this the most efficent way to forward the 'each' call to the Hash's native each method.

Should I make @index visible to the outside?

I'm a bit unsure as a block is invovled.

```
class TimeSlice
  def initialize(list)
    # @index is a hash
    @index = list.do_some_magic()
  end

  def each(&block) 
    @index.each(&block)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@index` should be private. No need to expose it outside the class scope.
Your example is perfectly fine if you only need to delegate the `each` method.

For more complex cases you can consider to implement a **Delegate** design pattern.
Ruby comes with a [Delegate module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to efficiency I dont think there is anything wrong with it. However, you should keep `@index` private, otherwise the whole point of the wrapper `each` method is lost.